# Capturing string ignoring escape sequence

Tags: string, escaping, awk, sequences

My input file has following entries:

```
0100000000010001000   1       GWSL7YE02GHT73, 
0010000000000000000   1       GWSL7YE02GU6GK, 
0000000000000000000   1       GWSL7YE02G5W2B, 
0010000000110000000   1       GWSL7YE02I364F, 
0000000000000000000   1       GWSL7YE02F4IOC, Escherichia_coli_O127:H6
```

How can I only capture line that have string at the end, such as line 5.
Another thing to note is that in each line at the there are two escape sequences "\t" "\n".
So in lines 1-5 do not think that after"," there is escape char "\n", BUT in reality it is ,"\t""\n".
I did had have following awk code:`awk '{if ($0~/[A-Z0-9_]$/) print$NF}'`, However, this assumes that there are either alphabets,number of undescore at the end. In reality the names can end with any special characters.I have tested hence I had to put an underscore"_". So is there a way other then this. Can I have something as `awk '{if ($NF!~/an expression that maps ,\n\t/}'`

Thanks

Comment: What are you looking to capture exactly, is it just `Escherichia_coli_O127:H6`? By the way, there is no line 6, only 5 lines are presented

Comment: No, there are many strings, shown is part of a file that have many more strings/scientific names/taxonomy. I had corrected the 6 to 5, not sure what its was not saved

Comment: @Sudeep: I'm just asking for the example given, I understand that this is generalized.  But what are you looking for as far as output for the sample input you just gave?

Comment: @Sudeep: also, is that a space or a tab `\t` between the comma `,` and the `E` in `Escherichia`?

Comment: @SiegeX between "," and "E" there is "\t"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look for lines that have fields greater than 3

```
awk 'NF>3' ./infile
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ cat -A lastfield
0100000000010001000   1       GWSL7YE02GHT73,^I$
0010000000000000000   1       GWSL7YE02GU6GK,^I$
0000000000000000000   1       GWSL7YE02G5W2B,^I$
0010000000110000000   1       GWSL7YE02I364F,^I$
0000000000000000000   1       GWSL7YE02F4IOC,^IEscherichia_coli_O127:H6^I$

$ awk 'NF>3' lastfield
0000000000000000000   1       GWSL7YE02F4IOC,   Escherichia_coli_O127:H6
```

Comment: +1. @Siegex, don't get hung up on the actual whitespace characters. By default, awk splits fields on "whitespace", doesn't matter if it a space or a tab. Also, awk ignores leading and trailing whitespace, unless you specify a field separator.

Comment: @glenn I was hung up on the space not because I thought awk cared but because I was first thinking of using `sed -n '/,  */p'` as the solution.  Then I just realized my awk solution of looking at number of fields

Comment: apologies, my comment was directed to @Sudeep.

Comment: @glenn aha. Thought you were commenting on my comments that I made in the OP =).  P.S., nothing to apologize for, we're all friends here =)

Answer (score 0):

you can also try

```
awk -F, 'NF>1' file
```

Comment: This doesn't work, they will all have two fields if you delimit on `,`. Try `awk -F, '{print NF}' file` to confirm.

Comment: @SiegeX, yes, i missed that out. Then using default FS would be better.